# How to Implement Microtransactions on the Amazon Appstore?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing, amazon-appstore

My company has an app that is available both in the Google Market and the Amazon Appstore. We're now looking to implement DLC in-app purchases. This is [no problem with Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html) but it looks like [Google doesn't allow 3rd party app stores to use their in-app billing system](http://blog.inner-active.com/2011/04/google-restricts-in-app-billing-to-android-market-not-so-open-after-all/).

Since we were free the first day on Amazon and have considerable users who downloaded our app freely we're trying to implement pay-DLC on Amazon to recoup the lost revenue. Google aside, I'm sure there are other ways to handle in-app purchases, any suggestions that people have had experience with that involve simple, streamlined, & secure APIs for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Appstore for Android does not yet support In-App Purchasing (aka In-App Billing). However, there is a beta of an SDK they are developing, and access to that SDK is by invitation only (again, as of this writing). You can sign up here:
http://www.amazon.com/gp/html-forms-controller/AmazonAppstore-IAPrequest

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of being able to use in-app purchases to buy from the Amazon Appstore. (I would post this as a comment but I can't seem to find the comment button.)
The only thing I can think of would be to update your application to look for files outside of your app - specifically additional content. An example would be PowerAmp, where it can use an unlocker to keep going, but it would be more useful... However, I don't think the app-store lets you do that.
You might just have to stick to the market.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's In-App Purchasing API (IAP) is publicly available.  You can download the Amazon In-App Purchasing API, Documentation, sample code, and testing tools here:

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk.html

---

*Opinion's expressed are my own, not my employer's.  For official Amazon Appstore policies and guidelines, please refer to http://developer.amazon.com